# Find the Mean Error of Irregularly Sampled Data

Tags: statistics, sampling, standard-error

I am creating an algorithm that estimates the State-of-Charge (SoC) of a battery. The table below, compares my algorithm with the true SoC.

| Predicted SoC | Real SoC | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 98.30% | 98.19% | -0.10% |
| 96.43% | 96.28% | -0.14% |
| 94.53% | 95.70% | 1.16% |
| 91.89% | 93.32% | 1.42% |
| 90.57 | 93.13% | 2.56% |
| 89.62% | 93.85% | 4.22% |
| 88.76% | 92.05% | 3.29% |
| 87.56% | 91.20% | 3.63% |
| 86.01% | 89.22% | 3.20% |
| 84.63% | 89.56% | 4.92% |
| 83.20% | 89.97% | 6.76% |
| 81.39 | 86.95% | 5.56% |
| 76.12% | 80.94% | 4.82% |
| 74.65% | 80.97% | 6.32% |

How can I calculate the Mean Error of my algorithm, since the samples do not have equally spacing between each other?

Comment: What does it mean that your samples do not have equal spacing between each other?

Comment: Can you define what is the "Mean Error"?

Comment: @Jellyfish In the Real SoC column, the difference between two rows it is not exactly the same each time. Some rows have a difference of 2%, while others have 6-7%. 
If my algorithm has big error in the region 80%->90%  but a very very small error in the region 90% -> 100%, then by having 10 samples at the region 80->90 and only 2 samples at the region 90->100 will product a false average error, if I average all of the errors together.

Comment: @PC1 I just want to find the average error of my algorithm. I think that "Mean Error" is correct here, but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different metrics of error you can use, one of which is mean squared error: $$MSE=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat y_i)^2$$

Another one is mean absolute error, given by

$$MAE=\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i-\hat y_i|$$

Clearly, there is a pattern in your model's errors. It is over predicting for the larger SoC's and underpredicting for the lower SoC's. Thus, the residuals wouldn't be symmetric/assumption of normality is not met: your fitted curve does not go through the data.